# Announcement: Monthly Joomla User Group Zoom Meetings

Tags: discussion

[image]

Every 3rd Tuesday of every month from 6pm to 8pm Australian Eastern Standard Time (0800 - 1000 UTC), Joomla Australia hosts [a virtual Joomla users group meetup online](https://www.meetup.com/JoomlaAu/).  If you plan to attend, please rsvp via the previous hyperlink.

While this is run by Aussies, the whole world is welcome to join us.  Topics are normally announced in advance, but there is always time for free discussion if you have something on your mind.

These events are 100% free, 100% volunteer organised, and 100% recorded.

You can read more and see past YouTube recordings [here](https://joomla.org.au/news-articles/australian-virtual-user-group-events).

Shout out to the Joomla Australia core team members for all of their efforts over the years:

- [@Nicky Veitch](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/13732)
- [@Michael Scruse](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/13674)
- [@Tim Plummer](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/14662)
- [@Stuart Robertson](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/12876)